# How to check when my widget screen comes to visibility in flutter like onResume in Android

Tags: android, flutter

In android if an activity is visible `onResume` is called. What is the equivalent method of `onResume` in **Flutter**?

I need the know when my widget screen is visible so I can auto-play a video based on that. I might go to another widget screen an when I come back it should auto-play.

My approach was to play the video in `didUpdateWidget` but `didUpdateWidget` is called every-time even the widget screen is not visible.

**Note:** I'm not asking about `didChangeAppLifecycleState` from `WidgetsBindingObserver` as it gives `onResume` etc callbacks for the app lifecycle not a particular widget screen.

Comment: Not duplicate . I mentioned that I'm not asking about `didChangeAppLifecycleState`. My use case is different @Tokenyet

Comment: When you are in the other screen, if you pop back to the video screen you can pass a parameter in the `Navigator.pop(context, parameter)`, so in the video screen you will get the parameter and do something accordingly. See this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/53861303/11020832

Comment: Oh, I finally know you are not taking about `onResume`. It's more about PageTransition, and look like you have the workaround. For not talking too much code, I prefer to stop before `Navigator.push` and `await Navigator.pop` to resume video. If you are not using `Navigator`, you might need to provide more code to show us :P

Comment: In the below answer which method is equivalent to onPause() and which method is equivalent to onResume() ? I'm assuming didPush() is similar to onResume() and didPop() is similar to onPause(). Am i correct ? Is my understanding correct ? I'm having confusion between didPopNext() and didPop(). Is didPopNext() also same as onResume() ?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

All of the problems are solved.

Put an observer on the navigator from the root of the widget tree (materialappwidget).

If you need more explanation please follow this link:
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/RouteObserver-class.html

I have implemented in my project and its working great @Sp4Rx

```
// Register the RouteObserver as a navigation observer.
final RouteObserver<PageRoute> routeObserver = RouteObserver<PageRoute>();

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: Container(),
    navigatorObservers: [routeObserver],
  ));
}

class RouteAwareWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  State<RouteAwareWidget> createState() => RouteAwareWidgetState();
}

// Implement RouteAware in a widget's state and subscribe it to
// the
// RouteObserver.
class RouteAwareWidgetState extends State<RouteAwareWidget> with RouteAware {
  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    super.didChangeDependencies();
    routeObserver.subscribe(this, ModalRoute.of(context));
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    routeObserver.unsubscribe(this);
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void didPush() {
    // Route was pushed onto navigator and is now topmost route.
  }

  @override
  void didPopNext() {
    // Covering route was popped off the navigator.
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Container();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this info. This is the nearest answer to `onResume` in Android. Marking as correct.

Comment: @Amit Here which method is equivalent to onPause() and which method is equivalent to onResume() ?  I'm assuming didPush() is similar to onResume() and didPop() is similar to onPause(). Am i correct ? Is my understanding correct ?  I'm having confusion between didPopNext() and didPop(). Is didPopNext() also same as onResume() ?

Comment: Good one! however it might be suggested to define the observer somwhere where it can be accessed from every where in the app like a global attribute.

Comment: Definitely you can declare it as global but as i declared final so I can access that from anywhere in my flutter application

Comment: @KPradeepKumarReddy in flutter it is not that simple as android the concept is about route add to tree and route remove from tree. you can check lifecycle of flutter route

Comment: In `routeObserver.subscribe(this, ModalRoute.of(context));`, `ModalRoute.of(context)` results into  `The argument type 'ModalRoute<Object?>?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'PageRoute<dynamic>'.`

Comment: @FerozKhan use `observer.subscribe(this, ModalRoute.of(context) as PageRoute);`

Comment: didPush -> When the current route is pushed (viewDidLoad + viewDidAppear)
didPop -> When the current route is popped (viewDidDisappear)
didPushNext -> When another route is pushed on top the current route (viewDidDisappear)
didPopNext -> When the next route which was directly next to current one gets popped (viewWillAppear or viewDidAppear)

I have given iOS equivalent lifecycle methods.

Answer (score 9):

I struggled to get a video to pause when not viewing the main screen of my app. I applied this `VisibilityDetector` and grabbed the `visiblePercentage` to force a pause or resume:

```
VisibilityDetector(
    key: Key('visible-video--key-${this.randomkeygenerator}-1'),
    onVisibilityChanged: (visibilityInfo) {
      var visiblePercentage = visibilityInfo.visibleFraction * 100;

      if (visiblePercentage < 1){ //the magic is done here
        if(_video_controller != null) {
          if(disposed_vid == false) {
            _video_controller.pause();
          }
        }

      }else{
        if(_video_controller != null) {
          if(disposed_vid == false) {
            _video_controller.play();
          }
        }
      }
      debugPrint(
          'Widget ${visibilityInfo.key} is ${visiblePercentage}% visible');
    },
    child: VideoPlayer(_video_controller)),


  @override
  void dispose() {
    // If the video is playing, pause it.
    _video_controller .pause();
    _video_controller .dispose();
    disposed_vid = true;
    super.dispose();
  }
```

Comment: Do you have videos inside a list? @petro

Comment: Ya,  `PageView` actually

Comment: Then this implementation is fine. But my query was different.

Answer (score 8):

Because the animation of the background route will be disabled. So we can judge whether it is in the foreground in this way:

```
final isForeground = TickerMode.of(context);
```

Wrap it into a widget:

```
/// Created by ipcjs on 2021/3/23.
class ForegroundDetector extends StatefulWidget {
  const ForegroundDetector({
    Key? key,
    required this.child,
    required this.onForegroundChanged,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final ValueChanged<bool> onForegroundChanged;
  final Widget child;

  @override
  ForegroundDetectorState createState() => ForegroundDetectorState();
}

class ForegroundDetectorState extends State<ForegroundDetector> {
  bool get isForeground => _isForeground ?? false;
  bool? _isForeground;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final isForeground = TickerMode.of(context);
    if (_isForeground != isForeground) {
      _isForeground = isForeground;
      widget.onForegroundChanged(isForeground);
    }
    return widget.child;
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm busy with other work actually. I will need some time to verify. Anyways this seems promising.

Comment: Thanks, exactly that I need.

Answer (score 7):

None of these existing questions exactly answered the question for me, so I wrote up a more thorough answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71279848/1759443) which talks about how to get *all* the same lifecycle methods as iOS and Android.

But the gist: I recommend using the [FocusDetector](https://pub.dev/packages/focus_detector) package. It **works exactly like onResume and onPause**. It would be implemented as follows.

```dart
class PageState extends State<Page> {

  void onResume() {
    log("onResume / viewWillAppear / onFocusGained");
  }

  void onPause() {
    log("onPause / viewWillDisappear / onFocusLost");
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FocusDetector(
      onFocusGained: onResume,
      onFocusLost: onPause,
      child: Text('Rest of my widget'),
      );
  }
}
```

Comment: Just tested this for MacOS and it doesn't work. Only for Mobile.

Comment: Looks like a great solution, but not compatible with latest version of Google mobile ads. Receive error: 'Because focus_detector >=2.0.1 depends on visibility_detector ^0.2.2 and google_mobile_ads 2.2.0 depends on visibility_detector ^0.3.3, focus_detector >=2.0.1 is incompatible with google_mobile_ads 2.2.0'

Answer (score 2):

It's probably not the simplest and definitely not perfect, but a while back I implemented events like those with routes. Basically, `EventRoute<T>` is a drop-in replacement for `MaterialPageRoute<T>` that provides optional callbacks for when the Widget is created, pushed to the foreground, pushed to the background and when it gets popped off.

**event_route.dart**:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

enum RouteState {
  none,
  created,
  foreground,
  background,
  destroyed
}

class EventRoute<T> extends MaterialPageRoute<T> {
  BuildContext _context;
  RouteState _state;
  Function(BuildContext) _onCreateCallback;
  Function(BuildContext) _onForegroundCallback;
  Function(BuildContext) _onBackgroundCallback;
  Function(BuildContext) _onDestroyCallback;

  EventRoute(BuildContext context, {
    builder,
    RouteSettings settings,
    bool maintainState = true,
    bool fullscreenDialog = false,
    Function(BuildContext) onCreate,
    Function(BuildContext) onForeground,
    Function(BuildContext) onBackground,
    Function(BuildContext) onDestroy
  }):
        _context = context,
        _onCreateCallback = onCreate,
        _onForegroundCallback = onForeground,
        _onBackgroundCallback = onBackground,
        _onDestroyCallback = onDestroy,
        _state = RouteState.none,
        super(builder: builder, settings: settings, maintainState: maintainState, fullscreenDialog: fullscreenDialog);


  void get state => _state;

  @override
  void didChangeNext(Route nextRoute) {
    if (nextRoute == null) {
      _onForeground();
    } else {
      _onBackground();
    }
    super.didChangeNext(nextRoute);
  }

  @override
  bool didPop(T result) {
    _onDestroy();
    return super.didPop(result);
  }

  @override
  void didPopNext(Route nextRoute) {
    _onForeground();
    super.didPopNext(nextRoute);
  }

  @override
  TickerFuture didPush() {
    _onCreate();
    return super.didPush();
  }

  @override
  void didReplace(Route oldRoute) {
    _onForeground();
    super.didReplace(oldRoute);
  }

  void _onCreate() {
    if (_state != RouteState.none || _onCreateCallback == null) {
      return;
    }
    _onCreateCallback(_context);
  }

  void _onForeground() {
    if (_state == RouteState.foreground) {
      return;
    }
    _state = RouteState.foreground;
    if (_onForegroundCallback != null) {
      _onForegroundCallback(_context);
    }
  }

  void _onBackground() {
    if (_state == RouteState.background) {
      return;
    }
    _state = RouteState.background;
    if (_onBackgroundCallback != null) {
      _onBackgroundCallback(_context);
    }
  }

  void _onDestroy() {
    if (_state == RouteState.destroyed || _onDestroyCallback == null) {
      return;
    }
    _onDestroyCallback(_context);
  }
}
```

And then to push your route you do:

```
Navigator.push(context, EventRoute(context, builder: (context) => YourWidget(context),
      onCreate: (context) => print('create'),
      onForeground: (context) => print('foreground'),
      onBackground: (context) => print('background'),
      onDestroy: (context) => print('destroy')
));
```

The context is a little icky though...

Comment: I'm not able to get your answer @software-person and `await Navigator.push(...)` works for me as @Tokenyet mentioned in comments

Comment: I created an EventRoute class. It is a class with which provides optional callbacks for when the Widget is created, pushed to the foreground, pushed to the background and when it gets popped off. All those events are optional. You can basically replace a MaterialPageRoute with this class and capture those events. But if @Toeknyet his/her solution works for you, you can use that one as well. I updated my answer

Comment: Though your answer has better approach, I will implement it somewhere and mark as correct.

Comment: @KPradeepKumarReddy Sources are my head and [the route class reference](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Route-class.html).